# Magento 2 - Apply coupon code on order excluding usage checks

Tags: magento-2.2.5, coupon-codes, magento2-enterprise

I want to apply `Coupon Codes` on edited orders regardless if that coupon is **active/expired**.

Right now my investigations lead me to the fact that `setCoupon` method of orders checks the validity of coupon automatically.

But I want sort of admin rights on that

i.e If I am admin than coupon usage checks should automatically be exempted.

Answer (score 0):

Magento does not have any feature of edit  Coupon Codes on order edit  page.In fact  **magento does not recalculated  order amount and it related related price after  order placed.**  Recalculation on order amount is not right idea .

i think create new order after cancel the last order, is best solution.